# Как удалить каталог на GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, удаление

В репо на гитлабе имеется несколько каталогов с ненужными мне файлами, которые я когда-то добавил.
Как мне теперь удалить каталоги из репо через GitBash?
(буду рад и решениям другими способами)

Comment: Используйте [git rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) `git rm -r <directory-name>`

Comment: Стоит отметить, что после `git rm` изменения еще следует закомитить и запушить. И что при этом ничего не удаляется, а наоборот, добавляется коммит для состояния без этих файлов / папок. Если хочется реально удалить, то для этого надо будет менять историю.

Comment: @user7860670, менять историю прямо в GitLab?

Comment: Нет, как обычно, локально, а потом пушать изменения на сервер.

Comment: @user7860670, извини, что доканываю, я только-только в этой теме.
Можешь, если не затруднит, рассказать как запушить изменения на сервер или скинуть ссылку на материал, где это объясняется?

Comment: коммит: `git commit -m "Some text here"`, пуш: `git push origin <your-git-branch-name>`

Comment: @Simon Спасибо большое вам всем! Но у меня осталась одна не решенная проблема: у меня есть каталоги, названия которых написаны через пробел. Когда я ввожу их названия через пробел, то пишет, что такого не существует. Как быть, как ввести их названия так, чтобы гит смог их прочитать и увидел их?

Comment: git rm "file name with spaces"